# How to show block of dynamic or static information at bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet

I want to display a sticky bar at the bottom of the screen to show dynamic or static data similar to the bars in the image below. Can this be achieved with `BottomSheetScaffold` on screen load without user interaction? If not, how else can this be implemented?

**EDIT:** I want to achieve this in Jetpack Compose.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This UI collection](https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui) might be a good starting point for you to see which elements/classes you need. It looks like you're depicting a [BottomSheet element](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)? Maybe an [AndroidSweetSheet element](https://github.com/zzz40500/AndroidSweetSheet) - Both of these look like they'd suit your purpose. You don't need the animations or can turn off the resizable, if you want them static. I'd start there with that huge collection of curated UI elements/widgets anyway, see if those two, or perhaps some other of the many UI element better fits your purpose.

For example, **this is the AndroidSweetSheet: ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5pTT.gif))**
[image]

**And heres the BottomSheet ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O80ml.gif)):**

[image]

Let the page load (lots of example images so may take a little while depending on your connection/CPU) but theres several that look like what you want. May have extras that you can turn off, such as the resizable nature of that AndroidSweetSheet, you can have it appear rather than slide up & scroll

Just having a look through that UI elements page (for my own app purposes) I noticed this one [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONF1K.gif) which might suit your purposes - imagine having a star pop up instead of the play icon, and when the user presses the star, it reveals your "Go premium" panel instead of the music player widget:

[image: FABReveal]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but these components seem to be designed for use with the Android View system. I was looking for components that will work with Jetpack Compose. What are your thoughts on that?

Comment: Ahh - my apologies! I'm thought you had tagged Android, and this is my go-to page for UI elements :(

Answer (score 0):

OP commented that they're specifically looking for jetpack compose - what about [this bottom-sheet?](https://proandroiddev.com/bottom-sheet-in-jetpack-compose-c8ab7a297aac?gi=bf246dcf319b)

Although this example looks very bare-bones, the structure **looks pretty close to what you're describing in yout text/images:**

[image]

You'd probably have the pop-up controlled so that it pops-up when you want it to, instead of the user clicking a button.

**Edits:** some more examples

[This code tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sliding-bottom-sheet-in-android-using-jetpack-compose/) also suggests building a bottom sheet using jetpack compose.

I'd think you'd probably want your "go premium" box to be modal, and [this page does just that, again with jetpack compose](https://developersbreach.com/modal-bottom-sheet-jetpack-compose-android/) - looks prettier, too!

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to have the `Sheet` appear as soon as the screen is loaded without having the user click on a button etc. in order to show the `Sheet`? And can I remove the sliding animation? I want the Sheet to be just a sticky bar at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: Absolutely - instead of attaching the action to a button, you would put the call to display the element in the view (probably want to attach this to ViewSwitcher?) or in the onCreate and have it display whilst rendering the main page?

Comment: Ok. But, this is going inside a `Composable`, not in the `Activity`.

Comment: That's okay - you aren't confied to using UI elements only in Activitys. You should be able to drop it into your composable. It's where the jigsaw analogy of a UI falls down. There isn't just one place where it fits - it'll go anywhere (slight exaggeration, but hope you get what I mean)

Comment: I understand. I managed to make this work by placing the `BottomSheetScaffold` inside a `LaunchedEffect` coroutine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can consider this one where you can utilize `LaunchedEffect` with a `Unit` key to show the bottom sheet immediately on first composition, and closing it using an Icon placed at the end of the gray "header".

All these codes are copy-and-paste-able so you can run it with no issues.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun MyScreenAutoShowBottomSheet() {

    val contentBackground = Color(0xFFa593b8)
    val sheetPeekHeight = 40.dp

    val bottomSheetScaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = BottomSheetState(BottomSheetValue.Collapsed)
    )

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){
        bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.expand()
    }

    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = bottomSheetScaffoldState,
        sheetBackgroundColor = contentBackground,
        sheetElevation = 0.dp,
        sheetPeekHeight = sheetPeekHeight,
        sheetContent = {
            Column(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(top = sheetPeekHeight)
                    .wrapContentHeight()
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .background(Color.DarkGray)
            ) {

                Row(
                    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
                ) {

                    Text(
                        modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                        text = "Go Premium"
                    )

                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.End
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .clickable {
                                    coroutineScope.launch {
                                        bottomSheetScaffoldState.bottomSheetState.collapse()
                                    }
                                },
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                            contentDescription = null
                        )
                    }
                }

                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(50.dp)
                        .background(Color(0xFF4fc992))
                )
            }
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor = Color(0xFF4a6ebd),
                shape = CircleShape,
                onClick = {},
            ) {
                Icon(imageVector = Icons.Filled.Add, contentDescription = "icon")
            }
        }
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(contentBackground)
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I had a hard time getting it to work properly especially by customizing it.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution without the use of sheets is to use a `Box` composable with the last element having a `Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)` modifier:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    //Main screen contents
    Column() {...}

    ...

    Row (
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(50.dp)
            .background(Color(0xFF4fc992))
            .padding(10.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        //Bottom bar contents
    }
}
```

[image]